# Public ASP.NET Application Security Considerations

Tags: asp.net, sql, security

An extremely secure ASP.NET application is having to be written at my work and instead of trawling through the Internet looking for best practices I was wondering as to what considerations and generally what things should be done to ensure a public web application is safe.

Of course we've taken into consideration user/pass combinations but there needs to be a much deeper level than this.  I'm talking about every single level and layer of the application i.e.

- Using URL rewrites
- Masterpages
- SiteMaps
- Connection pooling
- Session data
- Encoding passwords.
- Using stored procedures instead of direct SQL statements

I'm making this a community wiki as there wouldn't be one sole answer which is correct as it's such a vast topic of *discussion*.  I will point out also that this is not my forte by any means and previous security lockdown has been reached via non-public applications.

Comment: Trawling through the internet is the first step. Come back after you've done that and you'll learn more. :-)

Comment: I have trawled through the Internet, but there's more rhyme than reason.  SO is not just an active community but it's full of people who really know what they're talking about which is why I turned to asking this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bigger toppic than I think you perhaps realise. The best advice is to get someone that already knows who can advise you. Failing that I would start by reading the Microsoft document "[Improving Web Application Security: Threats and Countermeasures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994921.aspx)" but be warned that runs to 919 printed pages.

Answer (score 2):

You should refine the idea of "stored procedures" into just using parameterized queries. That will take care of most of your problems there.  You can also restrict fields on the UI and strip out or encode damaging characters like the pesky ';'...

Comment: added the ui stuff, didn't necessarily need a new post for something along the same lines...

Answer (score 1):

- use forms authentication instead of storing authentication data in session.
- Obviously: Hash passwords. If you want to be very cautious use SHA1 encryption instead of md5.